# bonobo method failed after overriden

Tags: python, overriding, bonobo-etl

I am using a light ETL library called bonobo.
The  csv writer bonobo.CsvWriter class has a factory method:

```
def writer_factory(self, file):
        return csv.writer(file, **self.get_dialect_kwargs()).writerow
```

with the docs:

```
class CsvWriter(FileWriter, CsvHandler):
    @Method(
        __doc__='''
            Builds the CSV writer, a.k.a an object we can pass a field collection to be written as one line in the
            target file.

            Defaults to builtin csv.writer(...).writerow, but can be overriden to fit your special needs.
        '''
    )
```

I'd like to add some extra parameters to customize my csv file, so I try to override it as such:

```
class quoCsvWriter(bonobo.CsvWriter):    
def writer_factory(self, file):
            return csv.writer(file, **self.get_dialect_kwargs(),quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC).writerow
```

when I add the node into the chain, the programs shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "geocoding.py", line 162, in <module>
    get_graph(),
  File "geocoding.py", line 135, in get_graph
    quoCsvWriter('db_addresses.csv')
  File "/Users/xxxx/xxxx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bonobo/config/configurables.py", line 152, in __new__
    missing.remove(name)
KeyError: 'writer_factory'
```

Any hints are appreciated.

Update:

meanwhile when I try to do

```
bonobo.CsvWriter('filename.csv',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

it throws error:

```
TypeError  "quoting" must be an integer
```

Comment: The "TypeError  "quoting" must be an integer" error had been fixed in the repo a while ago but never released (see #249), please upgrade to bonobo ~=0.6.2. I'll answer on the main question a bit later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of bonobo 0.6, overriding directly Method instances in subclasses is non trivial. Instead, you should provide an overriden implementation in the constructor arguments.

```
def writer_factory(self, file):
    return csv.writer(file, **{**self.get_dialect_kwargs(), 'quoting': csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC}).writerow

def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(
      extract,
      bonobo.CsvWriter('...', writer_factory=writer_factory),

    )

    return graph
```

If you really want to subclass for this use case, you can do it by overriding `get_dialect_kwargs()` method instead:

```
@use_context
class QuoteNonNumericCsvWriter(bonobo.CsvWriter):
    def get_dialect_kwargs(self):
        return {
            **super().get_dialect_kwargs(),
            'quoting': csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,
        }
```

This should work as expected.

Of course, overriding `quoting` is possible directly from  writer constructor as of bonobo 0.6.2, there was a bug before around this but fix is now released.

```
def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(
      extract,
      bonobo.CsvWriter('...', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC),
    )
```

All three methods have the exact same behaviour, you should favour the last one.

Hope that helps.